# Extracting tree cover values from Hansen to feature collection using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, feature-extraction

I would like to extract mean pixel value of treecover 2000 from Hansen from each geometry (polygon) of different shapefiles that I have import into Google Earth Engine (var table_comp). I create for this reason a  for loop.

This is briefly my script:

```
var gfc =ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2018_v1_6'); 
var treecover =gfc.select(['treecover2000'])

for (var py=0; py<19; py++){
  //var py=9;
  var year=py+2000

  var table_comp = load feature collection

  var tree_mean_value = treecover.reduceRegions({
    collection: table_comp,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale:30});
```

I would like to ask some clarification about the option scale of reduceRegions, in the help I read "A nominal scale in meters of the projection to work in" but I believe to not understand very well. I put 30 because I think this as spatial resolution of my starting image.

Can anybody can help me?